# Task scheduler: On Shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

In the Windows Task Scheduler, there is a trigger called "*On startup*". However, I'm looking for "***On shutdown***", but can't find it. Can you help me make a custom trigger equal in function to "*On shutdown*"?

Comment: Since you are doing this at shutdown (specific action) you can use a batch file in local Group Policy to do what you wish. I do not think Task Scheduler can operated at shutdown

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/844579/1737567  Check this answer, it explains it all.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.